# formatting date field from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, format

I am using a DATE field in my MYSQL table, and pulling it through on a php page. The problem is it comes out as "2011-04-23"

Is there a way I can reformat this as 23/04/2011?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2011-04-23"));
```

that should do it

[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: the problem is I need to keep it in this format in the database so I can use it to order by, but when I pull the data out of the database I need to convert it into a readable version if that makes sense?

Comment: yep well then you need elvenbyte's solution above that will format it it when still in the database ie (`MYSQL DATE_FORMAT`). Just to clarify though. i have a feeling you are storing your date field in a varchar()? You should have date field stored in date or datetime field then you have no problem sorting. **EDIT:** actually, ignore that. you are using date field. why is there a problem with sorting then? You should be able to sort (regardless of database format)... then in PHP format with `(date(), strtotime());`

Comment: good to hear :) also i just re-read my 2nd comment there, was a bit of a mess glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

DATE_FORMAT(date,format)

Look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming variable $date contains your MySQL data:

```
$date = '2011-04-23';
$timezone = 'Europe/London'; // this is optional argument

$formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date, new DateTimeZone($timezone));

// or without the optional timezone - where php will assume the default timezone from your OS

$formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);

echo $formatted->('d/m/Y');
```